# How to disable all touches for a Layout in Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am trying to implement a bottom sheet in `Xamarin.Android` and I want to disable all touches on everything that is not the bottom sheet (i.e. main layout), when the bottom sheet is active.

Main.axml:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:id="@+id/main_layout">
<include
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    layout="@layout/toolbar" />

<!-- Main Layou -->
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp" >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_test"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/logout"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_plus" />
</FrameLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/tint"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<!-- Bottom sheet -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/bottom_fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="160dp"
    android:background="#E0E0E0"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:elevation="16dp"
    android:translationY="160dp" />
```

I tried iterating over all the children and disabling them, but that changes the appearance of the button and I want to avoid that. I also tried setting the `Enabled` property of the layout to `false`, but the button was still touchable.

I think i need to somehow intercept all touches before they reach the button (and everything else that will be there later), but I don't know how to do that. By intercepting all touches I could also implement hiding of the bottom sheet after those touches.

Comment: One of a way could be to loop through your layout components as its a xml three and set all button and clickable component to disable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a transparent `RelativeLayout` that covers the entire screen and use the `android:clickable="true"` property in it to make sure it intercepts all the click events.

Then add `android:layout_alignParentBottom` to your bottom sheet and put it inside this newly created `RelativeLayout`. This way it'll appear at the bottom and everything else won't be clickable.

```
<FrameLayout>

  <!-- Main Layout -->


  <RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#0000"
    android:clickable="true">

     <FrameLayout
       android:id="@+id/bottom_fragment_container"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="160dp"
       android:background="#E0E0E0"
       android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
       android:elevation="16dp"
       android:translationY="160dp" />

  </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```